# Error registering Yodlee user, can't getWrappedExceptions

Tags: yodlee

I'm getting the following error (see Response) while attempting to register a user. The code was working fine before but it seems something changed.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:ns0="http://userregistration.usermanagement.core.soap.yodlee.com"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://common.soap.yodlee.com"
                   xmlns:ns2="http://login.ext.soap.yodlee.com"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns3:Body>
      <ns0:register3>
         <cobrandContext xsi:type="ns1:CobrandContext">
            <cobrandId>8910005960</cobrandId>
            <channelId>-1</channelId>
            <locale>
               <country>US</country>
               <language>en</language>
            </locale>
            <tncVersion>2</tncVersion>
            <applicationId>58EEA306454D869DFF721D0D00B82D00</applicationId>
            <cobrandConversationCredentials xsi:type="ns2:SessionCredentials">
               <sessionToken>05292013_0:718a0b8d870c13b5be2d2fb14bfd53b3796c5c97b401d68d34fe4594fdefeab3a3e5d6d8ee14696a6e03f53f0da613b781f1be0c8c06e70b883bb9abe232ba9f</sessionToken>
            </cobrandConversationCredentials>
            <preferenceInfo>
               <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
               <timeZone>PST</timeZone>
               <dateFormat>MM/dd/yyyy</dateFormat>
               <currencyNotationType>SYMBOL_NOTATION</currencyNotationType>
               <numberFormat>
                  <decimalSeparator>.</decimalSeparator>
                  <groupingSeparator>,</groupingSeparator>
                  <groupPattern>###,##0.##</groupPattern>
               </numberFormat>
            </preferenceInfo>
               <currencyCode>USD</currencyCode>
               <timeZone>PST</timeZone>
               <dateFormat>MM/dd/yyyy</dateFormat>
               <currencyNotationType>SYMBOL_NOTATION</currencyNotationType>
               <numberFormat>
                  <decimalSeparator>.</decimalSeparator>
                  <groupingSeparator>,</groupingSeparator>
                  <groupPattern>###,##0.##</groupPattern>
               </numberFormat>
            </preferenceInfo>
            <fetchAllLocaleData>false</fetchAllLocaleData>
         </cobrandContext>
         <userCredentials xsi:type="ns2:PasswordCredentials">
            <loginName>someyodleeuser@somedomain.com</loginName>
            <password>yodleepasswordtest</password>
         </userCredentials>
         <userProfile>
            <values>
               <table>
                  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">EMAIL_ADDRESS</key>
                  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">someyodleeuser@somedomain.com</value>
               </table>
            </values>
         </userProfile>
      </ns0:register3>
   </ns3:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>IllegalArgumentValueExceptionFaultMessage</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns4:IllegalArgumentValueExceptionFault xmlns:ns4="http://core.soap.yodlee.com">
               <faultText>com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException: Multiple exceptions encapsulated within: invoke getWrappedExceptions for details</faultText>
            </ns4:IllegalArgumentValueExceptionFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Problem is, I'm not getting back any details on the exception to debug the issue (Even when doing as suggested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password is not in the right format and hence you are getting this error.
Below are the restrictions on username and password which you should follow -

## UserName

- >= 3 characters <= 150 characters
- pNo Whitespace
- No Control Characters
- Contains at least one Letter

## Password

- >= 6 characters
- <= 50 characters
- No Whitespace
- No Control Characters
- Contains at least one Number
- Contains at least one Letter
- Does not contain the same letter/number three or more times in a row.  (e.g. aaa123 would fail for three \"a\"'s in a row, but a1a2a3 would pass)"); Does not equal username

Comment: Hi,I have edited the answer , please follow the steps now and let me know.